# Can the star tool in fireworks be used to create this star?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I used the star tool in Fireworks to create this star:

[image]

Can Fireworks be used to make this star look like this:

[image]

If no, then can Photoshop be used to create this star?

Thank you.

Comment: Almost _any_ design software can make a star like that, but you will still need to make the metallic look (gradients) yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best done as vector, but let's do it in bitmap. Photoshop has easy to understand tools for it.

At first draw a pentagon. It's a vector shape, but it is used only as quide. Then make a selection with polygonal lasso tool. Draw as a non-breking polyline all diagonals of the pentagon. The selection is your star shape. Fill it with a color into a new layer:

[image]

Save the selection for easy recall. You can need it later for example when testing something.

Select a half of the star and adjust it 10% darker with the curves tool:

[image]

Repeat it 4 times starting the selection every time from different cusp. Your star gets divided to segments that have different brightnesses:

[image]

The segments are now easy to fill with only 2 different shades. Use the paint bucket with low tolerance:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This can already be useful to something, but for glow select the darker areas one by one with the magic wand and fill the areas with a gradient:

[image]

The pentagon has no more any function, so it can be removed.

If you want the stroke, you can simulate it by making a little bigger colored star below the original. The original star was duplicated, stretched to a little larger size and turned to black with the curves tool and finally colorized to dark blue with Image > Adjustments > Hue&Saturation > Colorize.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Star Tool is practically *any* application will assist in drawing a star *shape*.

As far as I'm aware, none of the Adobe applications have the built in ability to ad dimensioning to the shape of a star, as in your second image.

The easiest way to achieve a star with the dimensioning would be to use a glyph from a **dingbat font**. For example, [Zapf Dingbats](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/itc-zapf-dingbats/medium/glyphs/553272/48) contains a similar star:

[image]

But you would then have to create outlines and edit further to add gradients.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this star looks a little bit different than the one I need. If you see the star I posted contains some effects like some glows and shadows.

Comment: **"....you would then have to create outlines and edit further to add gradients."** As far as I'm aware, *no tool anywhere* will create a star with gradient fills.

Comment: @Metis not if you took it out of a clip/stock art library. Nothing stops clip/stick arts being part of the software's functions ;). Although it is not really creating anything.